# Google Chrome for OS X not detecting update

Tags: macos, google-chrome

My version of Google Chrome on OS X doesn't seem to detect updates properly:
[image]

There is a new version (40.0.2214.93 as of this writing), as [the Google Chrome release blog](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/01/stable-channel-update_26.html) shows.
It doesn't give an error code. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried completely quitting Chrome and restarting it, as well as restarting your computer?

Comment: There was a restart installing the 10.10.2 update. Before and after that the same occurs.